# Hacking using Wireless Mouse Dongle

Tags: security, mouse

Yesterday my boss borrowed my wireless mouse and returned it after using it for 2/3 hours.

I want to know if he can install something in the connector/dongle to hack my system or access my system? Is that possible?

I have doubts because when I turned on my laptop this morning, I received a message that your device is ready to use while in fact I did not connect any new device.

Comment: Very very unlikely.

Comment: Did you insert the dongle in another USB port? In this case the computer will recognise it as a new device.

Comment: That would be silly. I think it's the mouseDaemon

Comment: Is your Boss a super hacker? I doubt it. Take your meds now.

Comment: I get that message every time I plug in my Kensington trackball after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely possible but that the message that "a device was connected" popped up does not mean that your mouse was tampered with.

http://www.dailydot.com/layer8/wireless-mouse-hack-password-study/
https://www.cnet.com/news/i-got-mousejacked/

There is alot of stuff online about how wireless mouse companies have been jacking up their security but you'd be surprised at the simplicity with which an exploit can be executed. When I was in boarding school I would sneak on to my science teachers PC and install keyloggers when he left the room so I could use his account information for unrestricted access on the server.
Back then I just copied what I found on the internet but I later found out that it is relatively simple coding using Python.